# Is it possible to access a controller's property in Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I wanted to know if its possible to access a property value in controller from Model? The scenario is for validations, the message for validations should come from controller property, which should be bound to model.

EDIT:
Example:
Controller.cs

```
public class RegistrationEmailConfirmController : Controller
{
    public string EmailConfirmation { get; set; }
}
```

Model.cs

```
public class RegisterEmailModel 
{
    [Display(Name = "Your email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]          
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegistrationValidationModel(**Property to be accessed here**)]         
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Should I create an instance of controller to access the property?

Can I get help on this?

Comment: for that you need to create class file for that. In you case you need to create `RegistrationValidation.cs` and for more you can get more from this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Comment: I already have a custom validation class. My issue is i need to get the validation message from controller's property and pass it to custom validation class. I want to know if that is possible?

Comment: why are you still create properties in `controller`.`Controller` is not for the properties. `Model` is the place where you can add all the property over there. If you go this way you can't use `mvc` principle very well...And you will get confusing.

Comment: You are right but the purpose of creating a property in controller is sitefinity. Sitefinity requires properties in controller to do content management from sitefinity backend

Comment: You cannot do it if you want the property to be added into one of the model ATTRIBUTES. Attributes are resolved at compile time so only static and const values can be used here.

Comment: yes. i was investigating on how to pass attributes dynamically. Thanks for the help. Il continue with my investigation on how to pass attributes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Because the Controller creates an instance of the Model, you can easily pass into the Model all the properties you like, including the error message text contained in the Controller that creates it, or even (if you wish) the instance of the Controller that creates the model.

Comment: I have edited the query, can you please help on how i can access the property?

Comment: The message for validation will be stored in controller's property, i need to pass that to custom validation class of model

Comment: @HarshithaK - as I said, your controlled controls the lifecycle of the Model, so when your controller creates an instance of the Model or deserializes it as part of the parameters being passed into the Controller, you can just set the validation message into a property of the model. Your code example for your controller doesn't contain any Action methods - these are where you would instantiate or deserialize the model.